# Error when compile: Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=14.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Using VS2010. When I compile my .NET project I get this error....

```
Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=14.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXX' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Do I have to have a version of Office installed for this to go away? I commented out the following lines in the web.config but the error keeps appearing!

```
 <!--<add assembly="office, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
      PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXX"/>
 <add assembly="Microsoft.Vbe.Interop, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
      PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXX"/>-->
```

Thank you in advance!